# Visit and invoke a variant of std::function

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm using a [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) to store different signatures of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)s. Said functions are stored in a vector, the latter being retrieved from a map.

How do I invoke each function in a vector of [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)? I feel like I should use [`std::visit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) but I can't figure out the correct usage.

```
#include <variant>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using var_t = std::variant<std::function<void(void)>, std::function<void(int)>>;
enum class EventEnum { A, B, C };

struct Controller {
    template<EventEnum E>
    void subscribe(var_t fn) {
        auto& callbacksVec = callbacks.at(E);
        callbacksVec.push_back(fn);
    }

    template<EventEnum E>
    void notify() {
        auto& callbacksVec = callbacks.at(E);
        for (auto& func : callbacksVec) {
            // std::visit([](auto& arg){ std::invoke(arg); }, func);
        }
    }

    std::map<EventEnum, std::vector<var_t>> callbacks;
};

int main() {
    auto fn = []() { std::cout << "lambda callback" << std::endl; };
    Controller myController;
    myController.subscribe<EventEnum::A>(fn);
    myController.notify<EventEnum::A>();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try writing visitor lambda according to those examples: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit ? Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: FYI you missed a few references in there, even if it did compile you would be modifying local copies and not `callbacks`.

Comment: Yes, so I've tried what's commented out in the question, I also tried copying the "overloaded operator()" example in your link, without success. But to be fair I'm still wrapping my mind around this and I don't fully comprehend it.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Could you be more specific? `auto func` should probably be `auto& func` but variant "must have no reference alternative"

Comment: @Fluffy I mean `callbacksVec`. (and the one you mentioned, although that is not that bad)

Comment: You're right, edited that in. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::visit` requires that every type inside the variant has a valid "action". If `func` were to have a `std::function<void(int)>` instead of `std::function<void(void)>` as it does right now, then there would be no way act on it. And because this (can) depends on the runtime, `std::visit` has to check at compile time that every possible alternative of the variant can be used to call your callable.

You can merge lambdas together for example, or have an `if constexpr` cascade for each type in the variant.

```
template<typename ...Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<typename ...Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

std::visit(overloaded{
    [](const std::function<void(void)> &Void) { std::invoke(Void); },
    [](const std::function<void(int)> &Int) { std::invoke(Int, 1); }}, func);
```

Comment: Sorry but unless I'm doing it wrong, this doesn't seem to be working? Call is ambiguous: https://godbolt.org/g/opi2Nn

Comment: Alright, thanks! I can work with that; both answers are valid, I'm choosing this one for the effort or fixing my code on godbolt, the extra explanation and because you were somewhat ahead in timing ;D

Answer (score 3):

Here is another example, adapted from [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) to your situation:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

 using var_t = std::variant<std::function<void(void)>, std::function<void(int)>>;

template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

int main() {
    std::vector<var_t> vec = {
        []() {std::cout << "void" << std::endl;},
        [](int arg) {std::cout << "int " << arg << std::endl;}
    };

    for (auto& v: vec) {
        std::visit(overloaded {
            [](const std::function<void(void)>& fv) { fv(); },
            [](const std::function<void(int)>& fi) { fi(42); }
        }, v);
    }
}
```